# Is it possible to only load part of mnist or other tuples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

Im busy building an OCR with `MNIST`, `Tensorflow` and `Keras` but I am having problems uploading the `MNIST` datasets because of an error with in `MNIST`. Can I upload only the first few items with out setting of an error

Comment: What error are you facing.? How are you loading the mnist data.?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear. However, below is how to load a data sample of MNIST using simple functions in TensorFlow and Keras.

**1). To load part of MNIST with TensorFlow.**

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

data = input_data.read_data_sets('./tmp/mnist_data', one_hot = True)

data_slice = 3000
train_x = data.train.images[:data_slice,:]
train_y = data.train.labels[:data_slice,:]
test_x = data.test.images[:data_slice,:]
test_y = data.test.labels[:data_slice,:]

train_x.shape
'Output': (3000, 784)
```

**2).To load part of MNIST with Keras.**

```
import keras

# import dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# flatten the features from 28*28 pixel to 784 wide vector
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784)).astype('float32')
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784)).astype('float32')

# one-hot encode the targets
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

data_slice = 3000
x_train = x_train[:data_slice,:]
y_train = y_train[:data_slice,:]
x_test = x_test[:data_slice,:]
y_test = y_test[:data_slice,:]

x_train.shape
'Output': (3000, 784)

y_train.shape
'Output': (3000, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the dataset manually from here and use what you need:

[MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)